# Jmeter Distributed Load Testing

Tags: jmeter

I am performing jmeter distributed load testing, On starting remote server from local machine in gui mode test starts but not able to store results on local machine.
It gives connection refused exception on server

Can any one suggest what could be the right step and solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating this?
java.rmi.server.hostname=[ip]

If hostname is updated, enable port 1099 in your local for incoming reequest or disable firewall in the local machine. So that server can contact local machine to send the results.

Comment: Ok...definitely you will be able to ping [ip] of your remote from our local. But..are you able to ping [ip] of your local from your remote? Can you try and confirm?   I doubt if it could be a firewall issue!

Comment: Then it is a firewall issue. Disable firewall or enable port (1099) in your local machine. It should work. 

I had the same issue. I resolved it by enabling the port.

Comment: can you please tell me how to enable this port and disable firewall. i am using ubuntu .